# Publishing single Form form a group of Forms

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In my ASP.NET(2.0),VB.NET Project,around 40+ Web Forms are there.The website is published to http://xxx.sg1.ihub.com/
Around 150 people are using this site inside the company

From these 40 Forms ,Can I to publish **one Form** (Visitor.aspx) to another site http://yyyy.zzzz.com.sg to make that form to be viewed by Public (internet users) ?

Due to security issue i don't want to publish the whole site to http://yyyy.zzzz.com.sg

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As JerSchneid mention, I have no idea what is your question is all about...

cause:

1. When you're saying FORMS, are you saying Textboxes, DropDowns, or actually `<form>` elements?
2. In ASP.NET you can only have 1 `<form>` element per page in order to use the inner input as web controls
3. Is this a 40+ pages all publishing into http://xxx.sg1.ihub.com/ ? So you have an action in the form element pointing to that site/page?

Because I don't know what your are talking about, I can give you an answer that I could think that is valid to the invironment that I imagine you have...

you can, in the http://xxx.sg1.ihub.com/ page that get's all the forms, create an if statement to transfer that call to other site/page

```
If Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER") = "http://http://xxx.sg1.ihub.com/formpage1.aspx" Then
   Server.Transfer("http://yyyy.zzzz.com.sg/mypublicpage.aspx")
End If
```

and you will get in that transfered url everything that was POSTed in the form.